# SQL Subquery within select from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query to pull back data made in our system and compare it to a separate table of invoices, which is working. However, now i need to to only pull that sum(volumnece) only for the invoices greater than the date entered in our system.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  
MIN(c.created_at) AS date,
c.meta_account_Id, 
c.organization_Id, 
c.user_id, 
c.meta_distributorId, 
c.meta_accountName,
CASE 
    WHEN sum(s.volumece) IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE sum(s.volumece)
END AS ces
FROM [commitments] c
LEFT JOIN [Sales2] s ON c.organization_Id=s.org_id AND 
c.meta_account_Id=s.account_id
WHERE c.status='active'
GROUP BY c.meta_account_Id, c.organization_Id, c.user_id, 
c.meta_distributorId, c.meta_accountName
```

Here is what I think it should look like but obviously incorrect:

```
SELECT  
MIN(c.created_at) AS date,
c.meta_account_Id, 
c.organization_Id, 
c.user_id, 
c.meta_distributorId, 
c.meta_accountName,
CASE 
    WHEN sum(s.volumece) IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE (SELECT sum(s.volumece) WHERE s.invoice_date>=c.created_at)
END AS ces
FROM [commitments] c
LEFT JOIN [Sales2] s ON c.organization_Id=s.org_id AND 
c.meta_account_Id=s.account_id
WHERE c.status='active'
GROUP BY c.meta_account_Id, c.organization_Id, c.user_id, 
c.meta_distributorId, c.meta_accountName
```

Basically the [Sales2] is a table of invoices and the [commitments] is a table of new invoices created in our system. Matching those up by account_id and then pulling all back from the day created and going forward, no invoices previous to the one entered in our system.

Examples:

This one should really sum up to 0 ces because all invoice_dates were after the date was enetered

[Commitments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlwS6.png)

[Sales2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBT72.png)

Comment: Why not just put `s.invoice_date>=c.created_at` as another *join* condition?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help your question.

Comment: Because then that join would narrow down my results where i just want to narrow down that "ces" sum. Basically I want to keep the results back as is, say 18 line items, then i want to narrow down the last col "ces" based on sum of invoices after the created at date

Comment: Join would narrow down my results in general

Comment: Will grab some samples of data, thanks for input

Comment: Example from commitments table: account_id: 123456, date: 10/10/17, ces: 19...................Example from Sales2 table: account_id: 123456, invoice_date: 09/10/17, ces: 10; account_id: 123456, invoice_date: 10/12/17, ces: 9;....................Notice how "ces" is summing to 19. I would like it to only sum the invoice, 2nd one in this example, that that invoice_date is after the commitments date

Comment: Sorry for sloppy comment

Comment: Have updated with pics

Comment: It's better put sample data also as text, just wrap it in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

I think your case statement needs to be in the sum() clause not outside of it.

```
sum( CASE WHEN s.volumece IS NULL THEN 0
          when s.invoice_date>=c.created_at then s.volumece
          else 0
          end)
```

Try to keep the sum(case ...) instead of case when then sum() end.    Make sense?  Case clause applies to each volumece and not to the total aggregate.

Probably not the most elegant use of the case null there either

```
sum( CASE when s.invoice_date>=c.created_at then coalesce(s.volumece,0)
          else 0
          end)
```

simpler?

Comment: Awesome yes works like a charm. And thank you for explanation as well too, makes perfect sense.